# Rotate + Zoom Image

Tags: jquery, canvas, rotation, html5-canvas, zooming

I need three basic functions for manipulating an image:

1. Rotate the image;
2. Zoom the image;
3. Move the image.

I'm now trying to zoom the picture, but it has to keep the rotated image, if I have rotated it.

And I need to move the image with the mouse while keeping the features of zoom and rotate if it is rotated.

```
jQuery('#zoom').click(function(){
  element.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  larguraNova = ( canvasWidth + (escalaPixel * valorZoom) );
  if(larguraNova > canvasWidth){
    /* passo a nova largura que é igual a altura */
    novosDadosWH = larguraNova;
    novosDadosTRBL = ( ( larguraNova - canvasWidth ) / 2 ) ;
  } else {
    /* passo o valor original */
    novosDadosH = novosDadosW = canvasWidth;
  }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/braziel/nWyDE/)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See here for some changes to allow zoom and keep rotation:

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/95r85zh4/)**

<strike>You don't need to use save/restore for this as you are constantly changing the zoom and rotation. Let them accumulate.</strike> Ok, I missed that you wanted to *translate* the canvas as well. In that case it will be complicated to accumulate so in that case DO use save and restore :)

However, you can refactor the code so that you do rotation and zooming in one place and moving in the mouse move event.

Move the translate to global (or as here, to your image load which normally is in global) so you have a center starting point.

The following modifications are made (see updated fiddle above):

```
// set delta for zoom and keep track of current zoom
var zoomDelta = 0.1;
var currentScale = 1;

// set delta for rotation and keep of current rotation
var currentAngle = 0;
var startX, startY, isDown = false;
```

Simplified load (I would recommend doing this on `window.onload` instead):

```
jQuery('#carregar').click(function () {
    element.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

    // the new refactored function common to all steps
    drawImage();

    jQuery('#canvas').attr('data-girar', 0);
    this.disabled = true;
});
```

The rotation functions are now reduced to:

```
jQuery('#giraresq').click(function () {
    angleInDegrees = 90;
    currentAngle += angleInDegrees;
    drawImage()
});

jQuery('#girardir').click(function () {
    angleInDegrees = -90;
    currentAngle += angleInDegrees;
    drawImage()
});
```

The zoom functions:

```
jQuery('#zoomIn').click(function () {
    currentScale += zoomDelta;
    drawImage()
});
jQuery('#zoomOut').click(function () {
    currentScale -= zoomDelta;
    drawImage();
});
```

To move the canvas we need to keep track of mouse down, up and move:

```
canvas.onmousedown = function (e) {
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    startX = pos.x;  // store current position
    startY = pos.y;

    isDown = true;   // mark that we are in move operation
}

canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
    if (isDown === true) {
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
        var x = pos.x;
        var y = pos.y;

        // translate difference from now and start
        element.translate(x - startX, y - startY);
        drawImage();

        // update start positions for next loop
        startX = x;
        startY = y;
    }
}

// reset move operation status
canvas.onmouseup = function (e) {
    isDown = false;
}
```

The refactored function now do all the clearing, rotation and zooming:

```
function drawImage() {
    clear();

    element.save(); // as we now keep track ourselves of angle/zoom due to
                    // translation, we can use save/restore

    element.scale(currentScale, currentScale);
    element.rotate(currentAngle * Math.PI / 180);
    element.drawImage(image, -image.width * 0.5, -image.width * 0.5);

    element.restore();
}
```

Comment: Hello Ken - Abdias Software
Tested your modified code was good, shorter and functional, thanks already.
But I realized that it is not rotating correctly with the code drawRotated changed for you. This problem is only happening here, and there also happens?

Comment: @MaxWilliamVitorino ah,yeah, just change `degreesInAngle += 90` to `degreesInAngle = 90` since they are accumulating by the rotation. Same for -= of course.

Comment: @MaxWilliamVitorino I'm not sure what you mean by wrong.. It rotates (+/- 90 degrees) -  what should be the proper action?

Comment: Hello Ken - Abdias Software
I did what you asked and it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: can you help me make the move part of the image when it is zoomed?

I tried doing this but it did not work. I used the mousemove to get the X and Y position

Subtraria the offset that is always 0 when I click with the mouse. And adicionava zoom rewriting the image. But in this case I have not used the tag of HTML5 scale, so do not know how to do now. Your code works perfect with 70 lines, with my old 230 lines do not.

Comment: @MaxWilliamVitorino Answer and fiddle updated with support for move. Note that now we "need" (easier this way) to use save/restore because of translate (move). Remember to up-vote.. ;)

Comment: As I use the zoom in function for the image, when I do move it, to any direction, the image is overflowing the area's limit, is there anyway to limit the movement of it when zoomed in or not. 

PS: I still did not vote in your question, because I have 5 reputation points, I need to evaluate 15! But I will certainly positively evaluate! You're giving me a huge help!

Comment: @MaxWilliamVitorino Just open a new question to address boundaries for the move.

Comment: FYI, there are a couple of typos in the JSFiddle, that make the example work, but only because it's a square image. The typos involve having 'width' instead of 'height'; hence, the example still works since the image is square.
To fix this, change the second 'width' on lines 72 and 77 to 'height' and it should work with any shaped image.

Comment: is there a way to remove those image trails left when you frag image in pane?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp) of the Canvas 2D API. There are methods available for [zooming (scale),](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_scale.asp) [translateing (moving origo)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_translate.asp) and [rotating](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_rotate.asp). All you have to do is apply these methods to the 2D-context of your canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// Rotate the image 45 degrees
ctx.rotate(45 * (Math.PI/180));
// Move it 20 px to the left
ctx.translate(-20, 0);
// Then zoom in by 50%
ctz.scale(1.5, 1.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/transformation.html) You can use the scaling feature to achieve a zoom function.