# HTML5 Canvas Move Image When Zoom

Tags: image, rotation, html5-canvas, zooming, mousemove

```
// Function to move imagem, when zoom
function moveImage(object, moviment , image){
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/braziel/nWyDE/

Friends, I have a hard time "how to" move an image when zoomed.

In the above code, the first 3 basic functions of the application are running. I carry a picture, I can rotate it left or right and I can also do a Zoom.

When I give zoom the image, I need to move it, but not exceeding the limit of the image.

I am using scale to zoom, but do not know how to move it.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by moving when zooming is that you only manage to scale the image so that it zooms on its top-left corner, and you would like to be able to zoom on a specific point inside the image, then the solution is usually to translate the point to the origin, scale and then translate back.

See this question: [Zoom in on a point (using scale and translate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916081/zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate)

Answer (score 0):

Friends, this problem was solved another post.
How to add image, image rotate and move the image.

[Rotate + Zoom Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426080/html5-canvas-rotate-zoom-image)